# Persistent BottomSheet below ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, bottom-sheet

I have an app layout with a custom `toolbar` and a persistent `BottomSheet` - both inside of a `CoordinatorLayout`.

On a button click I want to show the `BottomSheet`. Right now the sheet is displayed fullscreen and overlays the `toolbar`. By setting the app theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` the `BottomSheet` stays below the `ActionBar`, but the bar cannot be customized.

Is there a way to limit the height of the persitent `BottomSheet` to fullscreen - `ActionBar` height?

This is my code in `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:elevation="20dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:elevation="20dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_additem"/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code of `sheet_bottom.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor..."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]
The image on the left hand side shows the `BottomSheet` which stops below the `Toolbar` - which is not working with my current code. Currently it looks like the picture on the right.

Comment: can you upload a screenshot ?

Comment: Screenshots added to question - EDIT

Comment: how about you try to put a layout set its height from bottom to the toolbar and make the bottomsheet it's child and then set it to match it's parent height (the new layout)

Comment: Thanks! great and simple idea. One more thing to get it working BottomSheet must be a child of CoordinatorLayout!

Comment: as simple as setting coordinatorLayout to that new parent height so it will be like : Layout -> coordinator -> bottomsheet

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem... I don't know if it's the best solution, but for now, worked for me.

Try to put your include inside another CoordinatorLayout in your `activity_main.xml`, with a marginTop like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.test.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          app:elevation="20dp"
          android:elevation="20dp"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:elevation="20dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="56dp">
      
      <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_additem"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Its working for me even without margin, but what is the reason behind it?

Comment: thats an amazing hack xD.

Comment: This is not good way. Because in complicated view that inside this second Coordinator layout with combination of some other for example botton_sheet_behaviour, it will close or hide suddenly!

Comment: @Mahdi did you find the solution?

Comment: @BackPacker Yes. I find one. Using compose right now will solve all these issues.

Answer (score 3):

We can use app:layout_behavior instead of fixed height

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_additem"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sheet_bottom should look like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:elevation="@dimen/size_5dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
 </RelativeLayout>

 </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works when you expand the bottom sheet to the full screen, but when collapsing it, it adds additional margin that makes a part of the collapsing layout hidden below the screen, so I decided to put the margin programmatically by listening to the collapse/hidden status of the `BottomSheet`.

First add the `BottomSheet` within a `CoordintorLayout` in xml

And add below callback listener.

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

        CoordinatorLayout bottomSheet = findViewById(..); // inflate the bottom sheet
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams  layoutParams = 
             (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();

        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) 
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // remove top margin
         else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 100, 0, 0); // add top margin
        
        bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for updating the margin programmatically. While the hidden part of the BottomSheet can be offset by increasing the peek height, using just the original solution above means the margin projects onto the underlying UI elements so the scroll action area projects off the actual BottomSheet onto the other UI.

Using the onStateChanged method in the BottomSheetCallback means acting on the event that the BottomSheet has already expanded or collapsed. Adding or removing the margin at this stage can result in seeing 'jerky' behaviour where for example the sheet momentarily reaches the fully expanded state covering the appbar before the margin is then programmatically applied to shift the UI components down resulting in a 'flash' as this applies.

Instead I used the onSlide method to detect when the BottomSheet was being slid up or down and added or removed the margins only once the sheet was half way through the transition. If the margins are applied too early in the slide motion then again the user can see the BottomSheet UI jumping up or down not long after initiating the action (they are less likely to notice this at the half way point if they have done a 'fling' up or down motion.

Also I found it worked best to fetch the height of the AppBar and the status bar and use those to set the required padding value for accurate placement in expanded mode.

This challenge can be avoided altogether by using a widget to trigger the BottomSheet state change programmatically.

```
@Override
        public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            boolean inRangeExpanding = oldOffSet < slideOffset;
            boolean inRangeCollapsing = oldOffSet > slideOffset;
            oldOffSet = slideOffset;
            if (inRangeCollapsing && slideOffset < 0.5f) {
                //reset padding on top of bottomsheet so there is no padding/overlap onto underlying sheet (which overlaps underlying sheet and so interfers with scrolling behaviour
                bSheetView.setPadding(0,10,0,0);
                Log.d(TAG,"onSlide STATE_COLLAPSING");
            } else if(inRangeExpanding && slideOffset > 0.5f){
                //reset padding on top of bottomsheet so there is padding/overlap onto underlying sheet so it does not write over the top of the menu appbar
                bSheetView.setPadding(0, topMargin,0,0);
                Log.d(TAG,"onSlide STATE_EXPANDING");
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is oldOffSet please?

Comment: @tuanvn91 oldOffset is just a float declared in the new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() that contains the onSlide method being run above. You will see above it is set to the current value of the slideOffset which means on the next call to onSlide the current slideOffset can be compared with the previous one and therefore it is possible to tell the direction of the slide, either expanding or collapsing.